# How can I make the CSS Animation work on IOS Chrome?

Tags: html, css, ios, css-animations, css-transitions

I made an animation using only CSS that is not working on IOS (iPhone 11) Chrome. It's working on desktop Chrome, Firefox and Safari. But, it's not working properly on iPhone. I did try to implement `-webkit-` prefixes to the transforms, but, still couldn't get it to work.

```css
.message_bar {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #333;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.message_bar span {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.a111 {
  -webkit-animation: rotateWord0 10s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: rotateWord0 10s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: rotateWord0 10s linear infinite 0s;
}

.a222 {
  -webkit-animation: rotateWord 10s linear infinite 3s;
  -ms-animation: rotateWord 10s linear infinite 3s;
  animation: rotateWord 10s linear infinite 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  }
}

@keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord0 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes rotateWord0 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes rotateWord0 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="message_bar">
  <div class="message_bar_center">
    <span class="a111">banner 1 banner 1 banner 1 banner 1 banner 1 banner 1 banner 1</span>
    <span class="a222">banner 2 banner 2 banner 2 banner 2 banner 2 banner 2 banner 2 banner 2</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: does it work on iOS Safari? (you only mentioned desktop)

Comment: @Jasmine thanks for responding. It does work on Safari: https://codepen.io/medinage/pen/poyOQpE

Comment: I don't have an iphone to test it myself, which is why I mention to test it on other browsers on your iphone other than chrome iOS? will help work out if it is indeed a Chrome specific problem or a general iOS-browser related issue.

Comment: There are known bugs in iOS Chrome support for CSS Animations.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1249723

I'm not aware of any way to work around these.